# datagrid update command does not work? Am I missing something?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, sqldatasource

I am using **Datagrid** and SQLDataSource to bind data from just one table. In order to enable update, I have write update query which I wrong like this.

```
update mytable field1=@field1, field2=@field2 where ID=@ID
```

When I click edit, i get into edit mode. When I submit a change, the change is not submitted and I get no error. Do I need to change something somewhere else? I did not modify any C# code in this example.

**Edit:** 
If I omit where ID=@ID, then the whole column is successfully changed but it does not work with ID=@ID. What is wrong here?

**Edit**: Code

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [my_id], [ID], [FirstName], [LastName], [ApplicationUserName] FROM [member_tbl]" 

        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [member_tbl] SET [my_id] = @my_id, [FirstName] = @FirstName, [LastName] = @LastName, [ApplicationUserName] = @ApplicationUserName where ID = @ID">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="my_id" Type="Int32"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ApplicationUserName" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: @Bala, I actually renamed some of the fields for this post. The problems lies in ID=@ID and I don't know what is correct sytanx.

Comment: everything looks good; not sure why it's not working. Did you try including Type for all parameters ?

Comment: this code was generated by SQLDataSource automatically, so I did not feel the need to change it. It does work when i remove where ID=@ID but then it updates all the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself: I found that in order for this to work, the ID column *must* be the primary key (or may be unique column), otherwise it will not work and wont give you any error, which is a bit strange.